# i have a fragment contain List View, on a item click how to send position (int) to a new activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

i am creating simple counting app i create a main activity contain tab layout of two tab then each tab contain fragment on fragment i have a list view when and onitem clicked i like to stat a new activity

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ButtonCountActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

i like to get the  listView.setOnItemClickListener int i on ButtonCountActivity how ?

on newActivity i am counting and saving counted data to SQLdatabase i need this (int i) to select clicked item to update

on fragment

```
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {



            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ButtonCountActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("Value",i);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

on Newactivity

```
        Intent intent= getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("value");
    int value = bundle.getInt("value");
    Log.d("T","haha got u " + value  );
```

i am getting a null value i tried to fix my on i need help very very noob here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put int in "Value" and try to get it from "value" of course you will get null, both should be "Value" or "value"

change this

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ButtonCountActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("Value",i);
            startActivity(intent);
```

to this

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ButtonCountActivity.class);
             
                intent .putExtra("Value",i);
                startActivity(intent);
```

change this ..

```
Intent intent= getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("value");
    int value = bundle.getInt("value");
    Log.d("T","haha got u " + value  );
```

to this

```
int value;
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
                   value = extras.getInt("Value");

               }
```

Comment: Intent intent= getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("Value");
        int Value = bundle.getInt("Value");
        Log.d("T","haha got u " + Value  );

Comment: still same error

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.counter_v01.ButtonCountActivity.onCreate(ButtonCountActivity.java:35)

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'putInt' in 'Intent'

Comment: in new activity where to i put the code onCreate right

Comment: Yes right .....

Comment: intent.putInt("Value",i); ERROR  = Cannot resolve method 'putInt' in 'Intent'

Comment: do u mean "putExtra"

Comment: Ok use same your old code for listview , in new activity use my code should work if not then add onclicklistener inside adpater if you use custom adapter ..

Comment: i put extra same error null

Comment: keep your old code in fragment just change the code in the new activity .. check my answer again

Comment: still getting nothing

Comment: int value = 0;
                Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                if (extras != null) {
                    value = extras.getInt("Value");

                }

                Log.d("T","activity got u " + value  );

Comment: Check answer again i updated code for fragment and tested it should work now